# About RESTful API and JWT

Tags: php, laravel, rest, api, jwt

Base on `RESTful API` route likes:

```
  GET    user        // Get all user
  GET    user/{id}   // Get user by id
  PUT    user/{id}   // Edit user data by id
  POST   user        // create a user 
  DELETE user/{id}   // delete user by id
```

First question, As I know, the token instead of user ,then just need to parse the token that can clearly to know who that be, without `id` ,why need to parse it?

Second, if I need to modify user data that must be send such many request, is that something wrong? or that is the correct way?

```
client                   server 
            login   -->
      <--  get token
            token   -->
      <--  get user data
           modifiy  -->
```

And I using a `jwtAuth` to protected api route.

```
Route::get('user','UserController@index');
Route::get('user/{id}','UserController@show')->middleware('jwt.user');
Route::put('user/{id}','UserController@update')->middleware('jwt.user');
Route::post('user','UserController@store');
Route::delete('user/{id}','UserController@delete')->middleware('jwt.user');
```

Comment: I really don't understand your question. I tried but failed. Maybe it's just me. Sorry

Comment: @ConstantinGALBENU `PUT    user/{id}` need to parse id that can modifiy the target user , but I just getting the token when login,
how to get the current user id?

Comment: you can get using `Auth::id()`

Comment: @ConstantinGALBENU Is that means `login api` response within token and id, not just token?

Comment: That call return the user id